# Drupal mimemail problem

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-5

My drupal mimemail always adds a x- to our http:// on our images, thus killing them. I cannot figure out why this happens.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure that it is mimemail adding the x and not some other instance in the mail delivery chain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended up being google blocking images in email... *sigh*

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure that the problem is with mimemail, then it sounds like a question for the [mimemail issue queue](http://drupal.org/project/issues/mimemail).